# What is the difference between send() and sendline() in pexpect?

Tags: python, automated-tests, pygtk

I am new to pygtk, hence I have this question.
When clicking a Button in a window using Pygtk, how can I print the result on the Gui window rather than the console.
Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendline()` is just a convenience wrapper of `send()`. `send()` must be used if you don't want to press ENTER.

---

The following is from `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py` on my system:

```
def sendline(self, s=''):
    '''Wraps send(), sending string ``s`` to child process, with
    ``os.linesep`` automatically appended. Returns number of bytes
    written.  Only a limited number of bytes may be sent for each
    line in the default terminal mode, see docstring of :meth:`send`.
    '''
    s = self._coerce_send_string(s)
    return self.send(s + self.linesep)
```